# JPA Persistence entity with nullable composition

Tags: jpa

I'm trying to save - using JPA - the entity called "Proposta", and this entity has a composition with the entity "Motivo" (below my mapping)

```
@Entity
@Table(
    schema = "CADMAT",
    name = "TB_PROP",
    uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"TIPO", "COD"})
    }
)
public class Proposta implements Serializable, Identifiable {
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, optional = true)
@JoinColumn(
        name = "COD_MOTIV",
        columnDefinition = "NUMERIC",
        referencedColumnName = "COD",
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false,
        nullable = true)
private Motivo motivo;
...
}
```

But when I will create a new registry this error is reported:

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: 
br.gov.sp.sefaz.siafem.cm.db.model.Motivo@4ecd00b5.
```

I can't to put "CascadeType.PERSIST" because following my use case it's possible to save the entity "Proposta" without the entity "Motivo"

I already put the property "optional=true" and "nullable=true" in the annotations, but the error continues.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use cascade persist as you can still save/insert the Proposta entity with a null movito reference. If you don't use cascade persist, you are responsible for manually calling persist on the Movito you are referencing in Proposta before saving the proposta that references it.

Comment: If I use "cascade.PERSIST" the JPA will try inserting an empty entity - without primary key for example - and it will throw a DB exception

Comment: Actually I don't need save "Motivo" first and then save "Proposta". I just need saving "Proposta" ignoring the "Motivo".

Comment: Then you have your object model setup incorrectly.  If you want to save Proposta without Motivo, you must null out the reference.

Comment: I can't do that. My use case says when a common user inserts "Proposta", the composition "Motivo" must be ignored, and then - when a manager user updates this "Proposta" he must fill the composition. The composition "Motivo" must be optional

Comment: That isn't the way it works in JPA and optional doesn't mean what you think it means. Consider how you want to read it back from the database - do you expect a blank motivo to be read back from the DB? If the FK is null, that means there is no movito; the reference will be null too. If you have a reference, you are telling JPA the Proposta references something; even if the FK is read-only, the object itself must be maintained for caching, which is why the specification expects exceptions to be thrown if a managed instance references an unmanaged one like this.

Comment: When a manager fills in the Motivo, that is when you would set the reference, not before. Otherwise, the Motivo should be inserted, so that it exists with the Proposta that references it, and a manager can update it.

Comment: I already tried to set "Motivo" null, but the EntityManager throws me a NullPointerException. Because this I have an empty instance of "Motivo". I need to force EntityManager ignores this composition when "Motivo" will not be filled, but I don't know how

Comment: Are you sure the NPE is from the EntityManager? It shouldn't care that a property is null, but your methods, like equals/hashcode/toString and others might. An empty instance means something to JPA, so this isn't the right approach with an 'entity'.

Comment: You got the mistery!!! Actually I have a constructor method in "Proposta" and it was setting properties without verifying if "Motivo" was null or not. I fixed the constructor method and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the mistery Chris!!! Actually I have a constructor method in "Proposta" and it was setting properties without verifying if "Motivo" was null or not. I fixed the constructor method and it works.